# Footer <div> not staying at bottom of page when I scroll - CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer is not all the way on the bottom. It should be the very last thing on the bottom of page below the fold. All I need is to have a footer at the bottom of page, not the bottom of screen.

You can see it here: http://bit.ly/zftRi3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your footer from `position:absolute !important` to `position:relative` and it should flow with your page to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `<div id="footer">`. Since your footer is after all your other HTML, that is the default behavior.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/NwdGN/

Comment: I tried to change it, and it turn footer into sticky one. All I need is to have a footer at the bottom of page, not the bottom of screen.

Comment: @Acidon Then take off the `position: absolute;` entirely. That is the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#page-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 999px;
}

#footer {
    background: url("../../skin/fashion_mosaic_grey/css/../images/fashion_mosaic/horiz_separator.gif") repeat scroll left top transparent;
    clear: both;
    height: 68px;
}
```

Edit:

Remove the `bottom` property of `.footer` and it works. :)